# How to solve permission denied (publickey) error when using SSH

Tags: networking, ssh

I have edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd.config` to disable the password when connecting through ssh, I have done this as follows:

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd.config

PasswordAuthentication no

sudo service ssh restart
```

when connecting using ssh, it gives me this error `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Since you turned off password authentication, if you don't provide public key, it will reject you.  So what is your problem?

Comment: You should have a **private key** in the computer you are **trying to `ssh` from** and a **public key** in the computer you are **trying to `ssh` to**.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your public key from machine you are connecting from to the server. On the server put it into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Make sure this file has permissions '-rw-------'.

Answer (score 1):

You can find clues about why you're getting the `Permission denied (publickey)` error here:

```bash
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

If incorrect permissions:

```bash
chmod go-w /home/user
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If the user is locked:

```bash
usermod -U username
```

If the user was created programmatically:

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193131). The user might be locked if it has no password at all.

```bash
usermod -p '*' username
```